# jquery to fade images except for the image with mouse over it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <script>
       $(".playThumb").fadeTo("normal", 1);

        $(".playThumb").hover(function() {
                      $(".playThumb").not($(this)).fadeTo("fast", 0.3); },
      function() {
                      $(".playThumb").not($(this)).fadeTo("fast", 1);
                 });
         </script>

<body> 
<a href="#"><img src="artistry.png" class="playThumb" />
<a href="#"><img src="flavour.png" class="playThumb" />
<a href="#"><img src="quality.png" class="playThumb" />
<a href="#"><img src="Style.png" class="playThumb" />
</body> 
</html>
```

The images appear but nothing happens, whenever the mouse on the image other images it doesnt fade.

Comment: Your code is working see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/41oa6d1t/1/). What is the exact problem?

Comment: Add your code to `$(document).ready(function(){ ...});`

Comment: did you add jquery library in your code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Include jQuery library in the `<head>` section.
2. Add your JS code in DOM ready function.

   ```
   <script>
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $(".playThumb").fadeTo("normal", 1);

          $(".playThumb").hover(function() {
                $(".playThumb").not($(this)).fadeTo("fast", 0.3); 
          },
          function() {
              $(".playThumb").not($(this)).fadeTo("fast", 1);
          });
       });
   </script>
   ```
3. Your HTML does not have ending `</head>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

following code works for me

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

            $(".playThumb").hover(function () {
                $(".playThumb").not($(this)).fadeTo("fast", 0.3);
            }, function () {
                $(".playThumb").not($(this)).fadeTo("fast", 1);
            })
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .mouseover() event and try

Comment: just replaceed .hover() with .mouseover() nothing happened, the page remained static with images showing.